How to change font on SATO CL4NX via SZPL
Here is the issue: We use the SATO printer for label printing in our factory. We use a Python development that sends a .prn file to the printer with both static and dynamic content. This .prn file sends the data using SZPL, and so far, everything works well since the data is received correctly by the printer. However, the problem is with the font used for printing. Our goal is to use a .ttf (Courier New) font, but the printer always uses a default font, even though the font is installed on the printer using the SATO All-in-One Tool. Below is the .prn file that is sent to the printer:
^XA ^CI28 ^CW1,E:cour.ttf ^PW700 ^LL2300 ^MD16 ^PR8 ^FO125,30^A1N,30,30^FDManufactured by:^FS ^FO130,60^A1N,30,30^FDXXXXXXXXXXXX^FS ^FO100,90^A1N,30,30^FDXXXXXXXXXXXX^FS ^FO50,120^A1N,30,30^FD24710 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX^FS ^FO185,150^A1N,30,30^FDXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX^FS ^FO125,180^A1N,30,30^FDXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX^FS ^FO25,210^A1N,30,30^FDAvoid direct exposure to the sun.^FS ^FO125,240^A1N,30,30^FDTopical use only.^FS ^FO55,270^A1N,30,30^FDAvoid direct contact with^FS ^FO40,300^A1N,30,30^FDEyes and mucous membranes.^FS ^FO40,330^A1N,30,30^FDEvitar exposicion directa al sol.^FS ^FO95,370^A1N,30,30^FDSolo para uso tópico.^FS ^FO60,400^A1N,30,30^FDEvitar contacto con los ojos^FS ^FO85,430^A1N,30,30^FDy membranas mucosas.^FS ^FO130,480^A1N,40,40^FDLOT: XXXXXX^FS ^FO50,810^A1N,30,30^FDAvoid direct exposure to the sun.^FS ^FO110,840^A1N,30,30^FDTopical use only.^FS ^FO50,870^A1N,30,30^FDAvoid direct contact with eyes^FS ^FO60,900^A1N,30,30^FDand mucous membranes^FS ^FO50,930^A1N,30,30^FDEvitar exposición directa al sol.^FS ^FO110,960^A1N,30,30^FDSolo para uso tópico.^FS ^FO50,990^A1N,30,30^FDEvitar contacto directo con los^FS ^FO60,1020^A1N,30,30^FDojos y membranas mucosas.^FS ^FO10,1080^A1N,30,30^FXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX^FS ^FO10,1110^A1N,30,30^FDXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX^FS ^FO10,1140^A1N,30,30^FDXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX^FS ^FO10,1170^A1N,30,30^FDXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX^FS ^FO10,1200^A1N,30,30^FDXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX^FS ^FO320,1070^BQN,2,6^FDYYYY^FS ^FO20,1270^A1N,30,30^FD####################^FS ^FO20,1300^A1N,30,30^FD####################^FS ^FO20,1330^A1N,30,30^FD####################^FS ^FO20,1360^A1N,30,30^FD####################^FS ^FO20,1390^A1N,30,30^FD####################^FS ^FO20,1420^A1N,30,30^FD####################^FS ^FO20,1450^A1N,30,30^FD####################^FS ^FO20,1480^A1N,30,30^FD####################^FS ^FO20,1510^A1N,30,30^FD####################^FS ^FO20,1540^A1N,30,30^FD####################^FS ^FO115,1590^A1N,50,50^FDXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX^FS ^FO135,1860^A1N,50,50^FDLote:xxxxxxxxxx^FS ^FO60,1660^BY2^BCN,120,N,N,N^FD123456789012^FS ^FO160,1800^A1N,25,25^FD123456789012^FS ^PQ1 ^MMT ^XZ
I have tried embedding the font in the code, forcing the printer to use that specific font, downloading it to the printer, printing simpler codes using that font,... And nothing works, it always uses the default font.
